# Checkbox & Radio button Bootstrap CSS in ASP.net Update Panel

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox

I used this template for my ASP.net admin application:
http://themesseo.com/demo/admin-lte.html

And I used the checkboxes and the radio buttons like in the template (regular Bootstrap checkboxes and radio buttons). Everything works fine, but there's one place where I must put them into a Update Panel and when I open the page the first time, the checkboxes and radio buttons look fine. But when I submit and the Update Panel refreshed the content, every checkbox or radiobutton has lost its css (or js?) and they look like the default controls when they are not stylized.

What can I do so the css (or js?) are not lost on every update in the Update Panel? I tried with putting the css and js links again in the child page (because it's now in the master page) but without success.

Comment: @haraman answered your question correctly. It is irrelevant with your question but I strongly suggest you to upgrade adminLTE to latest version on site. https://almsaeedstudio.com/

Answer (score 2):

For many such themes to work, you usually need to initialize the design scripts again on `postback`. The link given above uses `iCheck` plugin to stylize CheckBox and RadioButton and the following snippet to apply the style:

```
$("input[type='checkbox']:not(.simple), input[type='radio']:not(.simple)").iCheck({
    checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_minimal',
    radioClass: 'iradio_minimal'
});
```

You can use following script in `WebForms` to register above snippet on `PostBack` *on child page* having `UpdatePanel`:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);
    function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
        if (args.get_error() == undefined) {
            registerPBackScript();
        }
    }
    function registerPBackScript() {
        $("input[type='checkbox']:not(.simple), input[type='radio']:not(.simple)").iCheck({
            checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_minimal',
            radioClass: 'iradio_minimal'
        });
    }
    registerPBackScript();
</script>
```

Put the above script at the bottom of the page and the styles should apply after `PostBack` also.